# hook_views_query_alter all condition

Tags: views, database

I have an exposed filter that shows products which have multiple entity references. The user should be able to pick some number of entities and the view should show entities containing all those references. In my mind that should mean changing the `in` operator on the where clause to an `all` operator.

```
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->vid == 7) {
    dpm ($query);
    if (isset($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['operator'])) {
      $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['operator'] = 'all';
    }
    dpm ($query);
  }
}
```

However this seems to have no effect. the operator is changed from the first `dpm` to the second and it does break if I enter some other value in the `all` does not change the results. Do I have the wrong operator? Or am I going about this all wrong?

[edit]
According to Payou the function should look like

```
function falk_products_query_products_alter($query) {
  $conditions = &$query->conditions();
  $conditions2 = &$conditions[0]['field']->conditions();
  $conditions3 = &$conditions2[0]['field']->conditions();
  $my_query = &$conditions2[0]['field'];
  $my_conditions = &$my_query->conditions();
  dpm ($my_query->conditions());

  if (isset($my_conditions[2])) {
    foreach ($my_conditions[2]['value'] as $target) {
      $my_query->condition($my_conditions[2]['field'], array($target), 'in');
    }
  }
  dpm ($my_query->conditions());
}
```

Which at the dpm's give me arrays that look good to me but dont work if more than one value is input. 
[image]

Comment: If I'm right, you want to alter $my_conditions[2] to an "IN" condition? But in your code, what is $my_conditions[2] initial statement? Because, in your function you add an "IN" condition to all $my_conditions[2]['value'] and I don't think that is you want... Can you dump sql query and each condition and specially the one who have values to transform to an "IN" condition.

Comment: I would like to have something more like an 'all' or 'contains' condition, meaning if the database entry has [1,2,3,4] I would like [1,2] to be a match and [1,2,5] not to be. so if all the numbers are in. I cannot find a query to match this other than 'if 1 is in and 2 in'.

Comment: Two possibles ways, continue to tweak that query and achieve your 'all' or 'contains' operator in Mysql style OR hook just after query execution and do it in php... You need to implement "hook_views_post_execute" for the second way. First way are better than the second but Second are easier to implement i think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering a query like this is really not recommended.

First of all, you should use SelectQuery methods provided by "$query" variable.
You can get an array of query conditions by using "SelectQuery::conditions()" method.

Be careful, if you want to alter this array get the array like the following snippet :

```
$conditions =& $query->conditions();
//Now you can use and alter your query conditions.
```

Some others tips related to your code :

**1) You can tag your query in Views UI**

Add a tag to your Views Query :
[image]

With this trick you can define a special hook for altering all query who use this tag. This hook is "hook_query_TAG_alter"

Now you can use this code :

```
function YOUR_MODULE_query_my_tag_alter($query) {
  $conditions =& $query->conditions();
  //This condition is useless now
  //if ($view->vid == 7) {
  //Check conditions and do your updates

  //}
}
```

**2) Careful to the module weight**

When you alter something, other modules can do it too...
This order is determined by the module weight saved in the "system" table.

By using your own tags on your query, other modules should not know about this tag and should not alter your query.

You can change your module weight but this is not the thread of this post

**Links**

[SelectQuery Api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7)

[SelectQuery::conditions() method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::conditions/7)

[Query Alteration recommandations by Drupal](https://drupal.org/node/310077)

[hook_query_TAG_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7)

[Change Module Weight](https://drupal.org/node/110238)

Comment: Thank you for the info. I added the results of what you said to do above. It still isn't working for me

Comment: The query variable uses the DatabaseCondition api not the SelectQuery api. FYI :)